# CSS styles not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have the following html file:

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>

<div>
   <input type="text" />
   <input type="email"  />
   <input class="button" id="clickme" type="submit" value="Click Me" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There is a link in the head block pointing to a css file that is:

```
body {  
    background: gray 
    background-image: url(“../images/bg-body.jpg”);
}

input[type=”text”], input[type=”email”] {
    border: none;
}
```

The background image loads but the two inputs still have a visible border. In both IE and Chrome. However, it works if I specify the style inline.

I am using Notepad++ to edit html and css. The ; wasn't a typo but shows another problem. If I specify both color and image, in IE the image shows but in Chrome it doesnt. Is there some priority at work here?

Comment: What program are you using to edit your HTML and CSS? You have multiple problems (your two latest questions) stemming from your use of `“` and `”`...

Comment: typo or not? on the second line there's no `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your CSS like below. Replace `”` with `"`

```
body {  
    background: gray;
    background-image: url("../images/bg-body.jpg");
}

input[type="text"], input[type="email"] {
    border: none;
}
```

**EDIT:**

By the way it will work without the quotation mark also.

```
body {  
    background: gray;
    background-image: url(../images/bg-body.jpg);
}

input[type=text], input[type=email] {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: The quotation marks are not necessary, it also works without them.

Comment: you are right. i will mention that also in my answer. thanks.

Comment: thanks! that solved all my issues. I guess I have to be careful when posting code from PDFs.